# Google App Engine PHP file upload

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, file-upload

I developed an API in PHP, hosted at Google App Engine, to use with my Android app.

Basically, when a user wants to change his profile picture, the android app send a request to the server containing the user id, the session key and the picture to upload. I want to upload this picture on the Google Cloud, but since Google App Engine require you to build a public upload URL to upload a file, how can I generate the upload URL and then use this URL to upload the profile picture in my Google Cloud in one request?

I tried to use a basic PHP redirect after generating the upload URL but I get a HTTP 405.

I am really stuck and I honestly don't understand why you NEED to create an URL before uploading a file to Google App Engine...

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading files to Google Cloud Storage from Localhost or external server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54342506/uploading-files-to-google-cloud-storage-from-localhost-or-external-server)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the photo that you want to upload on Google Cloud Storage saves as a Blob on GCS that's why they ask you to create a URL. Follow the document [1] it is related to Blobstore API in python but the concept of blob is same for any language so its good to read about blobs. Also find below a sample code which might help you to  upload a photo on GCS.

```
$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'bucket-name' ];
    $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload', $options);
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type ="file" name="fileupload" id = "fileupload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name ="submit">
 </form>

Upload Handler:
<?php
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
$gs_name = $_FILES['fileupload'];
$buffer = file_get_contents($gs_name['tmp_name']);
$bucket = CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();
$user_pic_url = 'gs://' . $bucket 
. (substr($final_file_path,0,1) != '/' ? '/' : '' )
. $final_file_path;
// set file options on Google Could Storage 
$options = stream_context_create( ['gs' => ['acl' => 'public-read', 
'Content-Type' => 'image/jpg']] );
echo "<br>";
$my_file = fopen($user_pic_url, 'w', false, $options);
fclose($my_file);
```

[1] **BlobStore API:** https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Answer (score -2):

```
$pdf->Output('example_025.pdf', 'I');
$DynamicNameofPic = rand(1000,10000)."_Invoice.pdf";
$FileNameDynamic = "gs://#######/".$DynamicNameofPic;
$pdf->Output($FileNameDynamic,'F');
$image_dataURL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/##########/".$DynamicNameofPic;
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_dataURL);$fileName = $DynamicNameofPic;
```